# Was The Prince by Machiavelli intended as satire?

Tags: 15th-century, literature, machiavelli

Researching Machiavelli's other works, I found online that there is a disagreement on whether *The Prince* was actually meant to be read as political satire.

http://www2.idehist.uu.se/distans/ilmh/Ren/flor-mach-mattingly.htm

The writer takes the position that *The Prince* is not inline with Machiavelli's other works, but I don't know enough about Italian history or the man to know if his evidence is strong.

Is there reliable evidence in favor of *The Prince* as a political satire?
Is there reliable evidence in favor of *The Prince* as a genuine guide?

Comment: Good question, but I don't think anyone knows this for sure.  Of course some people *think* they do, so it could still be answered and this question should be kept open . . .

Comment: Best satires are often genuine guides, too. :)

Comment: I'll say yes, but either way it is not a history question. Try literature maybe?

Comment: @TylerDurden, I think this question is applicable to both fields. Given that the study of History tends to be more rigorous, and that OP is about evidence of how Prince was intended to be perceived centuries ago, I would side with History stackexchange.

Comment: @TylerDurden I think it is on topic for both.  I actually tried to check if the literature stack exchange was a better fit, but I don't think it exists or at least I could not find it.

Comment: It was meant to be taken literally. Machiavelli wanted a united Italy with the foreigners kicked out, and correctly perceived this wouldn't be achieved by playing 'Mr Nice Guy'.

Comment: The question very precisely asks if there is **evidence** to support either hypothesis.  Answers should cite evidence; otherwise this degenerates into discussion.

Answer (score 3):

*The Prince* was not meant as satire but rather as a proffered training manual on how to be an effective ruler in a monarchy.  It was specifically intended for Lorenzo de'Medici by Niccolo Macchiavelli because he hoped that the book would be reviewed favorably enough that the de'Medici's would recall him from the exile he had been assigned to.  Several have suggested that the book was satirical in nature.  Rousseau has made this claim frequently.  I tend to think that it was what it was. He used the life of Cesare Borgia as a model for the young de' Medici in hopes that it would put him back in the good graces of that ruling family. Recall that he had actually been imprisoned and tortured by the de'Medici's for a short time after the fall of Florence.  I suspect that he was very earnestly trying to avoid a repetition of that unpleasant experience.  Whether he might have written the book as an allegory or double entendre is something Macchiavelli never said or wrote about himself so it will always be conjecture.

Comment: OK....so what's your (quoting the question here) "reliable evidence"? If your point is that there isn't any either way, you should probably lead with that.

Comment: Point taken.  Just move my last sentence to the lead off.  Since he never commented on this directly--so far as I am aware--the answer to this will always be a matter of conjecture. But my opinion is that Macchiavelli wasn't the type to engage in allegory that deep.